# How can I change the ingame UI skin easily?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change some game assets like backgrounds, images and buttons for another ones for an event and I want to let the players switch between the UI skins wherever they want.

Tested creating some GUI Skin but I think thats not what I want.

Right now, before build the game, I manually copy and paste new assets and replace old ones so the files have the same name and Unity changes every image in the game that uses that sprite. When the event finish I do the same with the old images. Bu I want to change that with just a button.

I know I could do the cahnge one by one but, there is any way to do this change withouth having to set all image sprites one by one? maybe changing the "baseSprite" name to "baseSpriteTemp" and the "eventSprite" name to "baseSprite"?

Any idea?

Comment: Why didn't GUI Skin work for you? Its purpose is exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Cant change the whole code now with GUI elements. Also never used them and I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

GUISkin is what you would use with the Immediate Mode GUI system, i.e. drawing in script OnGUI functions.

If you are talking about in game assets for the UI and other items, you have options:

1. Roll your own theming system
2. Use AssetBundle Variants
3. Use Addressable assets

I have used asset bundle variants in the past, and they were pretty easy to setup.

Addressables are a newer feature, and as such I have had little experience, but it looks like it can work for what you are looking for.